# Files not getting loaded/run from in vim plugin

Tags: vim, plugins, vim-plugin

I'm developing a vim plugin for a new (toy) language called `statemachine` as part of a bigger project.

I'm trying to get a valid compiler/makeprg loaded in for this file type and I have one defined in `compiler/statemachine.vim`

However, when I try to run `:make` or `set makeprg?` I get `make` and `makeprg=` respectively. I also cannot see `echom`s that I have defined inside `compiler/statemachine.vim`. So it seems that my code in the file `compiler/statemachine.vim` is not executing.

Specifically I'm attempting to get this registered with Syntastic as a valid syntax checker, and a pre-requisite for that is getting `makeprg` and `errorformat` set to valid values.

I am able to use an `equalprg` that I have set and can see `echom`s from `syntax_checkers/statemachine/statemachine.vim`, so I know that my plugin is being run in some capacity.

And the filetype is detected correctly: `set filetype?` yields `filetype=statemachine`

Directory layout of the plugin so far:

```
.
├── README.md
├── autoload
│   └── statemachine.vim
├── compiler
│   └── statemachine.vim
├── complete.sh
├── example.sm
├── formatter.sh
├── ftdetect
│   └── statemachine.vim
├── ftplugin
│   └── statemachine.vim
├── syntax
│   └── statemachine.vim
├── syntax_checkers
│   └── statemachine
│       └── statemachine.vim
├── test.txt
└── validator.sh
```

Relevant parts of the vim plugin code:

```
// autoload/statemachine.vim
function! statemachine#Errorformat()
    return '%f:%l:\ %m'
endfunction

//ftdetect/statemachine.vim
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.sm set filetype=statemachine

// syntax_checkers/statemachine/statemachine.vim
function! SyntaxCheckers_statemachine_statemachine_GetLocList() dict
    let l:makeprg = self.makeprgBuild({'args': ''})
    echom 'inside getloclist'
    return SyntasticMake({'makeprg': l:makeprg,
                        \ 'errorformat': statemachine#errorformat() })
endfunction

call g:SyntasticRegistry.CreateAndRegisterChecker({'filetype': 'statemachine',
                                                \'name': 'statemachine'})
```

The full vim plugin can be found here: https://github.com/scottopell/vim-statemachine

Comment: Why do you expect `compiler/statemachine.vim` to be sourced automatically?  On an unrelated side note: you don't need to escape the space in `errorformat`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Is that not how it works? I see this pattern referenced in multiple other plugins online and none of them manually call `compiler/<filetype>.vim`, so I assumed it was automatic similar to `syntax/<filetype>.vim` etc.

Comment: You  probably need to call `compiler statemachine` somewhere.

Comment: As @FDinoff points out, you probably need to add `compiler statemachine` to your `ftplugin`.

Comment: thanks, that did it. If one of you puts that as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Sato Katsura and FDinoff in the comments of my original question, I simply needed to add `compiler statemachine` somewhere. I chose to add it in `ftplugin`.